# Can IIS create threads from GPU cores?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, multi-core

Can IIS be set up to take advantage of new massively multi-core GPU's to provide additional thread for maximum concurrency?

My thought is that with technology like the AMD Fusion would it be possible to execute threads off of these  400+ cores to have a huge level of concurrent connections to a server.

If anyone knows a way to take advantage of these cores I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. GPU cores are (comparatively) very simple devices. They work great at massively parallel tasks, like rendering, encryption, and other math. They're basically horrible at logic, branching, and dependent operations (greatly simplified for the sake of argument). They also do not run the same code as a CPU.

A task like serving web pages involves almost no math at all; it's almost purely logic. If the webserver was rewritten to work on a GPU it would be substantially less efficient than one that runs on similar CPUs.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet no, as even development versions don't support DirectCompute/OpenCL/CUDA. In fact given the types of computing workload IIS does I doubt that the types of 'core/processors' in current GPUs would be much use in accelerating that kind of load. If Intel's 'Larrabee' had worked out then perhaps that would have helped but right now you're out of luck.